# Sum columns in dynamic range which are from another two columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, sum

I am working on making a dynamic table by adding columns in same row, however, range of columns is determined based on two columns colum_start and colum_stop:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
   'Name': ['Apple', 'Banana', 'Orange', 'Cherry', 'Egg', 'Cheese'],
   'ID': ['F1', 'F1', 'F1', 'F1', 'V1', 'V2'],
  '202101': [1, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50],
  '202102': [20, 15, 12, 18, 32, 12],
  '202103': [3, 11, 25, 32, 13, 4],
  '202104': [32, 11, 9, 82, 2, 1],
  '202105': [9, 5, 11, 11, 2, 5],
  'colum_start ': [202102, 202101, 202102, 202103, 202101, 202103],
  'colum_stop': [202105, 202103, 202105, 202104, 202102, 202105],
})
df
```

[image]

I want to create a sum_column that sums the columns based on colum_start and colum_stop in column name.

**desired output:**

[image]

Appriciate your help!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use numpy broadcasting for select values between both columns by compare by columns, and chained cumulative sums compared for `1`:

```
a = df['colum_start'].astype(str).to_numpy()[:, None]
b = df['colum_stop'].astype(str).to_numpy()[:, None]
c = df.columns.to_numpy()

mask = (np.cumsum(c == a, axis=1) == 1) & (np.cumsum(c[::-1] == b, axis=1)[:, ::-1] == 1)

df['SUM_OF_RANGE'] = df.where(mask, 0).sum(axis=1)
print (df)

     Name  ID  202101  202102  202103  202104  202105  colum_start  \
0   Apple  F1       1      20       3      32       9       202102   
1  Banana  F1      10      15      11      11       5       202101   
2  Orange  F1      20      12      25       9      11       202102   
3  Cherry  F1      30      18      32      82      11       202103   
4     Egg  V1      40      32      13       2       2       202101   
5  Cheese  V2      50      12       4       1       5       202103   

   colum_stop SUM_OF_RANGE  
0      202105           64  
1      202103           36  
2      202105           57  
3      202104          114  
4      202102           72  
5      202105           10
```

If small data and perfromance is not important use lsit comprehension with [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
c = df.columns.to_numpy()

df['SUM_OF_RANGE'] = [df.loc[i, str(a):str(b)].sum() 
                      for i, a, b in zip(df.index, df['colum_start'], df['colum_stop'])]
print (df)
     Name  ID  202101  202102  202103  202104  202105  colum_start  \
0   Apple  F1       1      20       3      32       9       202102   
1  Banana  F1      10      15      11      11       5       202101   
2  Orange  F1      20      12      25       9      11       202102   
3  Cherry  F1      30      18      32      82      11       202103   
4     Egg  V1      40      32      13       2       2       202101   
5  Cheese  V2      50      12       4       1       5       202103   

   colum_stop  SUM_OF_RANGE  
0      202105            64  
1      202103            36  
2      202105            57  
3      202104           114  
4      202102            72  
5      202105            10
```

Answer (score 2):

You can reshape with [`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html#pandas.DataFrame.melt), filter the rows based on your condition, and [`groupby.sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.sum.html):

```
df['SUM_OF_RANGE'] = (df
   .melt(['Name', 'ID', 'colum_start', 'colum_stop'],
         ignore_index=False)
   .astype({'colum_start': str, 'colum_stop': str})
   .query('(variable >= colum_start) & (variable <= colum_stop)')
   .groupby(level=0)['value'].sum()
)
```

Or another numpy approach based on a mask, extract the date columns, broadcast the comparison with your start/end and [`sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html) only the relevant cells:

```
# get date columns
dates = df.columns[df.columns.str.match(r'\d{6}')]

# get cells with start <= date <= stop
m = (  (df['colum_start'].astype(str).to_numpy()[:, None] <= dates.to_numpy())
     & (df['colum_stop'].astype(str).to_numpy()[:, None] >= dates.to_numpy())
       )

df['SUM_OF_RANGE'] = df[dates].where(m).sum(axis=1)
```

Output:

```
     Name  ID  202101  202102  202103  202104  202105  colum_start  colum_stop  SUM_OF_RANGE
0   Apple  F1       1      20       3      32       9       202102      202105            64
1  Banana  F1      10      15      11      11       5       202101      202103            36
2  Orange  F1      20      12      25       9      11       202102      202105            57
3  Cherry  F1      30      18      32      82      11       202103      202104           114
4     Egg  V1      40      32      13       2       2       202101      202102            72
5  Cheese  V2      50      12       4       1       5       202103      202105            10
```

Answer (score 2):

A possible option by [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html)*ing* a [`sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.sum.html) on a [`slice_indexer`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.slice_indexer.html) :

```
df["SUM_OF_RANGE"] = df.apply(
    lambda s: s.iloc[
        s.index.slice_indexer(
            *map(str, s[["colum_start", "colum_stop"]]))]
        .sum(), axis=1,
)
```

Output :

```
print(df)

     Name  ID  202101  ...  colum_start  colum_stop  SUM_OF_RANGE
0   Apple  F1       1  ...       202102      202105            64
1  Banana  F1      10  ...       202101      202103            36
2  Orange  F1      20  ...       202102      202105            57
3  Cherry  F1      30  ...       202103      202104           114
4     Egg  V1      40  ...       202101      202102            72
5  Cheese  V2      50  ...       202103      202105            10

[6 rows x 10 columns]
```